# Deploy regular solana (not anchor) on mainnet

Tags: solana-program, rust, deploy, mainnet

I'm looking to deploy a regular solana program written in Rust **(not anchor)** on mainnet. For some reason I can't rewrite it using anchor solana. I have searched online and all failed. Does anyone know the detailed answer?

Comment: I'd advice patience. This might be unrelated to your program as mainnet isn't currently active for user transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run `cargo build-sbf` or `cargo build-bpf` (depending on version) to build your program. That will build a `.so` file in `target/deploy` directory.
2. To deploy on mainnet, you need a wallet containing **real SOL**. Copy wallet private key

[image]

and paste it in the javascript code below

```
const bs58 = require('bs58')
const fs = require('fs')
b = bs58.decode(
    'your private key'
)
j = new Uint8Array(
    b.buffer,
    b.byteOffset,
    b.byteLength / Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
)
fs.writeFileSync('key.json', `[${j}]`)
```

3. Try run above code to create `key.json` file
4. Run `solana config set --url https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com`
5. Run `solana program deploy -k *path_to_key.json* *path_to_.so_file*`

Answer (score 3):

You use `cargo build-sbf` or `cargo build-bpf` (depending on you used version) to build your program. That will build a `.so` file in your `target/deploy` directory. From there you can use the `solana program deploy` command to deploy your program. To see relevant info about that run `solana program deploy --help`.